# Date formatting issue in python

Tags: python-3.x

```
import time
import sys
import json as json
import spacy 
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.parser import parse
def format_source_date(date):
    if date != None:
        try:
            try:
                dt = parse(date)
                date_formatted=dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
                print(date_formatted)
            except:
                print(date)
        except ValueError:
            print(date)
def has_seperator(text):
    if ',' in text or '/' in text or '-' in text:
        print(text)
        return True
    else:
        return False

date = 'Sep 25,2017'
has_seperator(date)
format_source_date(date)
```

The required answer is 09/25/2017. Instead taking current year 2021 . Is there any solution to solve this issue

Comment: I'm afraid this question isn't very clear.  Perhaps boil it down to what you're trying to do and ask again.

Comment: It seems fairly clear to me. The output of `format_source_date` is `09/25/2021` when they expect it to be `09/25/2017`.

Comment: I have give a date "Sep 25,2017". But if I run this program I am getting the output as 09/25/2021. I need to get output as 09/25/2017. This program is taking current year instead of 2017.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems your date string is not a valid format,
See the following

```
>>> parse('Sep 25,2017')
datetime.datetime(2021, 9, 25, 0, 0)
>>> parse('Sep 25 2017')
datetime.datetime(2017, 9, 25, 0, 0)
```

so already have a `has_seperator` function, use it remove the character or use a supported format

Comment: A document is in date format like 'Sep 25,2017'.  How to change to Sep 25 2017 by removing comma

Comment: @Ajay You could do something like `parse(date.replace(",", " "))`.

Comment: I'm surprised, I thought `dateutil` was smarter than that.